# How to create a class to display toast message once when image button clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have more than one image button on my app and I want it to display a toast message when each buttons are clicked. However in my code I don't like the idea of it having continous toast message set for each image button over and over again. Is there a way to shorten these messages like in a class if so how can I do it? Note: The only one I dont want the toast message to appear on is the room service button.

My code:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton roomservice, transportation, foodservice, maintenance, checkout, baggagecollection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MainMenu");

    roomservice = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.roomservice);
    transportation = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.transportation);
    foodservice = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.foodservice);
    maintenance = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.maintenance);
    checkout = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.checkout);
    baggagecollection = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.baggagecollection);

    roomservice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openRoomServiceMenu(); // creates main menu method name
        }
    });

    transportation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "This action is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    foodservice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "This action is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    maintenance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "This action is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "This action is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    baggagecollection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "This action is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good practice to Not To Repeat Yourself

so You can pass an object of a custom listener class

```
private class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener // make an inner class
{ 
  String msg;
  MyListener(String msg){this.msg = msg;} // if you want separate msg for each image , otherwise omit the constructor 
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view){
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  }
}
```

Now set it to Button like

```
maintainance.setOnClickListener(new MyListener("your msg"));
```

Comment: Hi. im getting an error saying `cannot find symbol variable LENGH_LONG`

Comment: sorry, spelling mistake, it is LENGTH, you know it already , it is in your question

Comment: Hi. I get an error on `MainActivity.this` which says `not an enclosing class`

Comment: as i mentioned in the comment in answer you need to implement it as an inner class, that means class i provided need to be inside the body of your MainActivity class

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. But if i want the same message to display on each button do i have to setOnClicklistener to each button with the same text repeated? Or is there a alternative way to display the message. For e.g if i wanted "your msg" to repeat on all image buttons when clicked would i have to copy and paste each line of code?

Comment: no as i mentioned in the comment in the answer is your msg is the same for all buttons then there is no need to keep the constructor , you can remove the constructor, and in the toast instead of msg pass the message as a string resource. and then you can call button.setOnClickListener(new MyListner()) only , because now you only have no arg constructor which is there by default

Comment: I also felt that you don't have a good basic knowledge of the language , so will recommend to please  learn the concepts of java first before going into the android world, otherwise your journey in that world will be full of obstacles , and you're welcome ChickenMan

Comment: there is a right tick button , you can press if someone has given a satisfactory answer

Comment: Thankyou. I had to read your message over 10 times to finally comprehend it. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest to create entire new class of ImageView if it just shows toast when its clicked. what you can do is to create new type of click Listener which will implement View.OnClickListener and take string or string resource as constructor parameter. after that override onClick In your new click listener and show toast there. in the end set your view's click listener your newly created class and pass string in constructor you want to show in toast. that way you wont be forced to create new type of class if you want to have same functionality with buttons or other types of views.

Comment: its very helpful that you also provided an example

Answer (score 1):

You can create method inside your Activity

```java
void handleClickWithToast(String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, message, length).show();
}
```

or even shorter

```java
void handleClickWithLongToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and call it inside click listener

```java
transportation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handleClickWithLongToast("This action is unavailable");
    }
});
```

or You can create utils class with static methods

```java
class ToastUtils {
    public static void showShortToast(Context context, String message) {
        showToast(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    public static void showLongToast(Context context, String message) {
        showToast(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    private static void showToast(Context context, String message, int duration) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).show();
    }
}
```

You can also create custom `View.ClickListener`

```java
public class LongToastClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String message;

    LongToastClickListener(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ToastUtils.showLongToast(view.getContext(), message);
    }
}
```

and apply it on your buttons

```java
button.setOnClickListener(new LongToastClickListener("Message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of this way to reduce your repetitive code

Simply create a separate class and define static method on that class to show toast

```
public class CommonUtils {
 public static void showToast(Context context,String message){
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Then call this method from Activity/Fragment

```
CommonUtils.showToast(this,"Your Message");
```